# Remove the database migration plugin from Grails project

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

when I try to build a war in bamboo for Grails 2.2.1 I get:

```
/apps_01/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/BUYIT-MERCHANTBRIDGE-DEPLOY/MerchantBridgeServer/grails-app/migrations does not exist.
21-Mar-2014 12:47:24            at org.apache.tools.ant.types.AbstractFileSet.getDirectoryScanner(AbstractFileSet.java:483)
```

Google tells me to put the `migration` directory there.  I would prefer to just remove the plugin, which I believe comes with grails by default from version 2.x on.

I can uninstall the plugin locally, but how do I do it so that when bamboo checks out my war and builds it, it knows that my application doesn't care about this directory because it doesn't use this plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Plugins are registered in `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`. When you create an app or a plugin a default set are included there, but any of them can be removed or replaced. Just delete the entry for this plugin and it will be uninstalled the next time you do a dependency check (e.g. when running `grails compile`) and will not be installed in Bamboo.